# In this example of circular motion, how does the net force act radially?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force

A metal rod is bolted down on one end. The other end has a rocket firmly attached, pointing perpendicularly to the rod. Before the rocket is turned on, the system is at rest. Thus net force $= 0$.

When the rocket is turned on, the only new force is thrust, which acts to the right (or left). If the net force when the rocket was off was $0$, how can the new net force be acting radially towards the centre?!

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that when you say that one end of the rod is "bolted down" you mean that it is pivoted so that the rod can turn about this end.

In that case, the rocket's thrust will give the rocket end of the rod a tangential acceleration. As the rod picks up angular speed, $\omega$, there will be a growing radial acceleration $r\omega^2$ as well. The force providing this radial acceleration (of the rocket and rocket end of the rod) will be the tension in the rod.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but; the rocket provides tangential acceleration, which leads to circular motion, which in turn somehow creates tension in the rod? Is this because the rod is trying to prevent the rocket's detatchment? And surely that means circular motion does not actually need a radial net force, just a tangential one - at least in the beginning?

Comment: (1) Rod prevents rocket moving in straight line and is therefore under tension. (2) At the beginning the radial acceleration is indeed negligible, because the rocket is hardly moving, whereas the tangential acceleration  is finite. As the rocket picks up speed the radial acceleration increases as $v^2$,

Comment: Okay! So as the rocket picks up speed, the force required to keep it moving at that radius increases, and thus the tension in the rod increases and radial acceleration increases? Right?

Comment: That's it! Well done for your persistence!

Comment: It says I should avoid saying thanks but I don't know how else to say it, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Initially **just after** the rocket has been turned on, the only force is perpendicular to the rod, causing acceleration of the rod.

But assuming the rod is strong enough (and doesn't break) the rocket is **immediately** forced to change direction because it moves on a circle (forced to do so by the rod).

This change in direction causes *centripetal acceleration* $a_c$, acc.;

$$\vec{a_c}=\frac{\text{d}\vec{R}}{\text{d}t}=-\omega^2 \vec{R}$$

Where $\vec{R}$ is the position vector (pointing outward) and $\omega$ the angular velocity.

Assuming the rocket keeps thrusting, this is not the only acceleration. If the thrust $F$ is constant then the rocket will also experience *tangential acceleration* $a_t$:

$$\vec{a_t}=\frac{\vec{F}}{m}$$

The total acceleration $\vec{a}$ is the vector sum of both:

$$\vec{a}=\vec{a_c}+\vec{a_t}$$

Assuming that only the rocket has significant mass, then the net force is:

$$\vec{F_{net}}=m\vec{a}$$

[image: Acceleration diagram]

Comment: I now understand that the rod causes the radial force, thanks! However, I am stil confused... I thought Centripetal acceleration was the result of the centripetal force, which is the net force. So how can there be another "tangential acceleration" if the net force leaves only a radial force which leads to centripetal acceleration?

Comment: The 'tangential acceleration' happens when the rocket keeps exerting a force. 'Centripetal acceleration is caused by centripetal force' is correct but doesn't contradict what I wrote. One could also write 'centripetal acceleration needs centripetal force'. These are interchangeable concepts: one cannot live without the other.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't get it. Looking at your diagram you show **a**c and **a**t. My question is, since **a**c must come from the net force which accounts for all forces, how can you draw another "**a**t" and make a new net "**a**"??

Comment: As long as your rocket is providing thrust, it will accelerate *along* the circle. That is $a_t$. But to stay *on* the circle and thus constantly change direction *centripetal acceleration* $a_c$ is needed and this is provided by the bar. The sum of the thrust and the force provided by the bar is the total, net force $\vec{F_{net}}$.

Comment: Look at it another way: after some seconds the rocket motor stops. Now the rocket's tangential velocity $v_t$ is constant in size and there is *only* centripetal acceleration needed to keep the rocket on its circular trajectory.

Comment: Okay, so as long as there is a centripetal force the object will stay in circular motion, but it needs a tangential force to make it accelerate - and in this case that is provided by the rocket? Don't you mean angular acceleration as it will only rotate faster?

Comment: Angular acceleration ($\alpha$) or tangential acceleration ($a_t$) are both correct terms in this context. But they're not the same: $a_t=\alpha R$ Yes it will rotate faster but its velocity on the circle also increases.

Comment: Ok. I've finally got it. Angular acceleration is simply another way to describe the tangential acceleration caused by the rocket. And if the rocket stays on, it becomes a case of non-uniform circular motion with both tangential and radial components. Thanks sm!

Comment: Yes, I think you were 'overthinking' it a bit! ;-)